# Why isn't chruby saving my default Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-install, chruby

I'm setting up a new machine and trying to install Ruby with chruby. I used ruby-install to install both ruby 2.3 and 2.1.2 because that's what everybody else on my team is running.

When I run `chruby` I get:

ruby-2.1.2
   ruby-2.3.0

Then I run:

```
chruby ruby-2.1.2
```

and:

```
$ chruby
* ruby-2.1.2
  ruby-2.3.0

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

The problem is that when I close terminal and open it again the default Ruby version goes back to ruby-2.3.0. How can I set a default version with chruby?

Comment: Sounds like the `chruby` stub isn't getting activated properly when you create a shell. Are you sure it installed successfully?

Comment: how would I check?  when I run chruby, it find the command and runs it...

sorry, I'm still new to mac. 

I installed it with homebrew

Comment: I'm more familiar with `rvm` and `rbenv`, but they all work on the same principle. The [installation instructions](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) includes a step where you have to add a line to `~/.bashrc`. Did you do that? It's easy to miss.

Comment: I tried it in .bashrc, then I moved it to ~/.bash_profile

it's:

source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh

Comment: do I have to have a .ruby_version file?

Comment: A `.ruby-version` file is to set the version for a user or a project. It's not strictly necessary but can be useful. If absent should go to the global default, if there is one.

Comment: Remember to check with `which ruby` as to the one you're using, and look at `echo $PATH` to see that the `chruby` stuff is in there properly.

Comment: so I added 2.1.2 to a .ruby-version file in my home directory, seems to be working now

thanks everyone!

Comment: If you solved it and understand how, add an answer here that explains it in a bit more detail. You're probably not the only one with this issue, and who knows, in the future you might forget and come back here to remind yourself.

Comment: well, I don't know that I solved it per se.  but it's a fix for now I guess.  and ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Invoke Chruby at Shell Initialization

Unlike RVM or other Ruby managers, chruby doesn't really have a concept of a "default" Ruby. You need to actually define one during each shell initialization. To do this, you need to:

1. Source the chruby.sh script.
2. Select the default Ruby to be exported to your environment.

As an example, you can add the following to your shell's ~/.bashrc or other interactive-shell startup file:

```
. /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh
chruby ruby-2.3.0
```

Answer (score 4):

so, the fix I've found so far is to put in a .ruby-version file in my home directory.

currently the .ruby-version file looks like:

2.1.2

... that's it, just the number of the ruby version I wish to use by default.

Answer (score 1):

To set the chruby default ruby version, you need to use the "u" glob qualifier.

Example:
`chruby u ruby-3.0.0`

`#=>  * ruby-3.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Use `chruby` to list Ruby versions. Then type `chruby [version]` (in my case, `chruby ruby-2.6.5`).